# Calling scalar function from c# using Entity Framework 4.0 / .edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, user-defined-functions

I would like to map my scalar function to my .edmx but it fails. I right click on my entity framework mapping, and choose update model from database. It appears in my stored procedures folder in my model browser.

However, when I want to add it to my `Function Imports` folder in the model browser, the message **scalar function does not appear** shows in the drop down list. Can someone help me?

I can call the scalar function using the old way, such as:

```
dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<DateTime?>(
"SELECT dbo.getMinActualLoadDate ({0}, {1}, {2}) AS MyResult", 
LoadPkid, LoadFkStartLoc, TripSheetPkid).First();
```

but it is not the best way. My manager would like me to find a way be able to put the scalar function in the "function import" folder so I can call the scalar function using the following code instead of the previous code:

```
dbContext.ExecuteFunction("getMinActualLoadDate ", paramList);
```

I tried to add an image to display what I mean but as my reputation is still low, I am unable to do so. However the image could be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/756865e5-ff25-4f5f-aad8-fed9d741c05d

Thanks.

Comment: Please change your title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 17):

I've encountered same problem. And here is solution I've found my self suitable enough (tested in EF5, but should also work in EF4):

There is no support of mapping scalar-value functions out of the box but you can execute them directly.

You can also edit edmx file to make edmx generate proper method for scalar-value function, but it ll be deleted if you ll synch you model with database.

**Write scalar-valued function implementation yourself:**

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT [dbo].[CountMeals] ({0})";
Object[] parameters = { 1 };
int activityCount = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sqlQuery, parameters).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Or edit edmx and add Xml for custom maping of scalar-valued function:**

```
<Function Name="CountActivities" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false"    NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false"   ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <CommandText>
        SELECT [dbo].[CountActivities] (@personId)
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

This information was found in this [blog post](http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/)

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution to this issue, which is almost exactly what your manager was asking for.. albeit 18 months late.

As an vanilla method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calls a given Sql function and returns a singular value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="db">Current DbContext instance</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">CLR Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="sql">Sql function</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Sql function parameters</param>
    /// <param name="schema">Owning schema</param>
    /// <returns>Value of T</returns>
    public T SqlScalarResult<T>(DbContext db, 
                                string sql, 
                                SqlParameter[] parameters,
                                string schema = "dbo") {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("function");
        }

        if (parameters == null || parameters.Length == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("parameters");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("schema");
        }

        string cmdText =
            $@"SELECT {schema}.{sql}({string.Join(",",
                parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.ParameterName).ToList())});";

        // ReSharper disable once CoVariantArrayConversion
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(cmdText, parameters).FirstOrDefault();

    }

}
```

And as an extension method to EF:

```
namespace System.Data.Entity {

    public static class DatabaseExtensions {

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls a given Sql function and returns a singular value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="db">Current DbContext instance</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">CLR Type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="sql">Sql function</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">Sql function parameters</param>
        /// <param name="schema">Owning schema</param>
        /// <returns>Value of T</returns>
        public static T SqlScalarResult<T>(this Database db, 
                                           string sql, 
                                           SqlParameter[] parameters,
                                           string schema = "dbo") {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql)) {
                throw new ArgumentException("sql");
            }

            if (parameters == null || parameters.Length == 0) {
                throw new ArgumentException("parameters");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema)) {
                throw new ArgumentException("schema");
            }

            string cmdText =
                $@"SELECT {schema}.{sql}({string.Join(",", 
                    parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.ParameterName).ToList())});";

            // ReSharper disable once CoVariantArrayConversion
            return db.SqlQuery<T>(cmdText, parameters).FirstOrDefault();

        }

    }

}
```

Though it doesn't smoke here, I would suggest unit testing before any serious use.

Comment: didn't you need to change "SELECT dbo.{0}({1});" to "SELECT * FROM dbo.{0}({1});" ?? or did your just work the way you had it. Just wondered.

Comment: Yes, I've since used this extension method in a production project and the parentheses are intended.. though you may be able to just get away with a space between the function name and the argument also.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. This method works perfectly and also makes use of SqlParameters.

Comment: and what if the requested function does not exist on SQL Server? This code is not 'ready' for production purposes in my opinion. Sure a good suggestion and ready to get started with :-)

Comment: @RobAngelier I see you point about production 'readiness'.  However, the EF team's own extension methods don't appear to be handling any remote exceptions either:  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/eece19ded562ba8aa85f2173d3280a23fc4e3727/src/EntityFramework.Relational/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs.  What would you expect this method to return if an exception was caught here?

Comment: @dperish i would throw a custom application exception with more specific details. You could verify if the SQL method that's being called, exists on SQL server and throw an exception with the name of the function etc. if not. This way it's much easier to debug your application when something goes wrong.

Comment: @RobAngelier Incidentally, I did come across a production issue with this extension in preparation for a large green-field project, though it was related to the hard-coded schema name.  I'm going to have to go ahead and disagree with you about checking for the existence of the target Sql object.  Any production-ready projects I'm working in should have adequate test coverage and proper exception handlers implemented in the domain layer. The EF team's approach here is clear.  Adding an additional query to check that the function really, really does not exist would one too many responsibilities.

Comment: I get this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String SqlScalarResult[String](System.String, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

Comment: I am assuming you're using this in a larger expression with VB.Net.  Any change you could post a little more to provide some context?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you miss the [`Edit Function Import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456824%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) dialog, where you can generate *Complex Types*. try to explore.

[image]

If you have successfully created the `scalars`, you can now navigate like this

```
using (var con = new DatabaseEntities())
{
   long? invoiceNo = con.sp_GetInvoiceMaxNumber(code.Length + 2).First();
   ....
}
```

Comment: Hi spajce, basically that's what I intend to do. but my scalar function name that I have created does not event exist in the storedprocedure name drop down list (although I have add the scalar function in my model browser). If it is a stored procedure it appears in the DDL, but if it is table/scalar function, It doesn't appear in the DDL. therefore I am having difficulty to call my scalar function in the way I intend as I have mentioned in my first post. Thanks

Comment: And issue still exists in EF 6.1.2 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/756865e5-ff25-4f5f-aad8-fed9d741c05d/add-scalar-function-to-function-import-folder-in-model-browser-of-entity-framework-40-edmx?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 1):

The one and the only solution is to convert the function scalar type to table value type with a single value in the table, please see the code sample.

**You don't have to change anything in the EDMX XML, please modify the SQL function**

> Scalar function as it was, which doesn't work

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha256]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(32)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT * FROM HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str) AS HASH256 );
END -- this doesn't work.
```

> Scalar function -> Converted to Table Valued function , it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha2561]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @returnList TABLE (CODE varbinary(32))
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str);

    RETURN; -- This one works like a charm.

END
```

Edmx screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code in page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (MayEntities context = new MayEntities())
        {
            string str = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select dbo.HeyYou()").Single().ToString();
            Response.Write(str); //output:'Hey this works'
        }
    }
}
```

scalar function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HeyYou] ()
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'Hey this works'
END
go
```