# Call a Scalar valued function in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I call a scalar function in entity framework 6 ?
I have tried the following code

```
        using (MhEntities DContext = new MhEntities())
        {
            var Account_IdParameter = Account_Id.HasValue ? new ObjectParameter("Account_Id", Account_Id) : new ObjectParameter("Account_Id", typeof(long));
            string res = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DContext).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<string>("MoneyforHealthEntities.Fn_LEVEL0_Acount_Id", Account_IdParameter).FirstOrDefault();
            return Convert.ToInt64(res);
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Answer (score 15):

No need to use `ObjectContext` to do this.  Also, I don't think you can simply pass in the name of the function, you need to give it complete, valid SQL.

So I would try something like this instead:

```
using (MhEntities DContext = new MhEntities())
{
    string res = DContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT MoneyforHealthEntities.Fn_LEVEL0_Acount_Id(@p0)", Account_Id).FirstOrDefault();
    return Convert.ToInt64(res);
}
```

Since you didn't give any details about which database you are using, or the exact function definition, it's possible that the above may need further tweaking.  But it should at least give you the basic idea.

Comment: Hi, I have used string res = DContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT [dbo].[Fn_LEVEL0_Acount_Id](@p0)", Account_Id).FirstOrDefault(); to make it working. no need to use entities.fn

Comment: I tried this with SQL Server 2008 and EF 6 and received error that indicated @p0 must be declared.  [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19654014/2788458) does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime ServerTime = new ContextDbEntities().Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("Select getdate();").FirstOrDefault();
MessageBox.Show(ServerTime.ToString());
```

Comment: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." *[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*

Answer (score 0):

All the answers right but if someone uses a `stored procedure`, it needs to be edit on function import by:
1. Right-click on your `function` then click on `edit`.
2. On the `edit function Import` window.
3. Select `Scaler` on the `returns a collection` section.
4. Finally, click ok and save your model.

In my example, I call an Insert stored procedure that returns a string value.

```
using (DbModel db = new DbModel())
 {
     string result = db.storedprocedureName(value1,value2).FirstOrDefault();
     return result;
 }
```