# How do I use a SQL function from C# code section using Entity Framework in MVC 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have a SQL Function like this, named `AgeCalc`

```
USE [DB_test]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[AgeCalc]    Script Date: 01-Jul-16 3:31:52 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AgeCalc]()
RETURNS NUMERIC(9,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @birth_date DATETIME
    DECLARE @today_date DATETIME
    DECLARE @age NUMERIC(9,2)
    SELECT @birth_date = DofB FROM dbo.Table_formula
    SELECT @today_date = InpDate FROM dbo.Table_formula

    RETURN CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), @birth_date -@today_date )
END
```

How can I call this `AgeCalc` function from my C# code end? I have called a procedure in this way

```
DBC dbc = new DBC();
dbc.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_user>("inT_pop @id", new SqlParameter("@id", 2)).ToList();
```

Here `inT_pop` is my procedure name, is the same way I can call a function too?

Comment: Have a look here, it can be your answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729442/call-a-scalar-valued-function-in-entity-framework-6?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
YourContext.CreateQuery<bool>(
"SELECT VALUE YourModel.Store.UserDefinedFunction(@Parameter1) FROM {1}",
new ObjectParameter("Parameter1", Parameter1Value)).First();
```

Hope this might be helpful

Comment: It seems that you have tried in ADO.NET, but the questioner asked for a solution in Entity Framework

Comment: @user2256217, I am using a function with EF not with ado.net. you might be confused please have a closer look.