# I got error in ASP.net LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetBreakTypeColor(Comsol.Champ.DRS.Domain.Model.RoomsAlloc)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

when i run this code i got error

```
  public async Task<List<CaseData>> GetRoomAllocAsync(bool status)
        {

            var data =Context.RoomAllocs.Where(c => c.Status == status)
            .Include(p => p.Room).Include(p => p.Case).Include(p => p.Collector)
            .Select(
            v => new CaseData
            {
                CaseId = v.CaseID,
                Notes = v.Case.Notes,
                SubcategoryId = v.Case.SubcategoryId,
                RoomName = v.Room.Name,
                BreakType = v.Case.BreakType,
                color = GetBreakTypeColor(v),
                SubcategoryName = v.Case.Subcategory.Name,
                SUName = v.Collector.ForeName + "" + v.Collector.SurName,
                FDate = v.FDate,
                TDate = v.TDate

            }
            ).ToList();
            return data;


        }
public static string GetBreakTypeColor(RoomsAlloc r)
    {
      
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: are you understanding why you got that error? The code is being converted to a sql statement, and it does not know how to translate your method `GetBreakTypeColor` into sql.

Comment: there is alot of confusion about how to translate means ,this function just return a string in string member @Jonesopolis

Comment: @Jonesopolis mentioned the main reason for the error. For the solution, 1. Write a scalar function and [use EF to call the scalar function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31729442/8017690) by passing value. 2. Materialize the query and bring this string transformation task to work in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you force [immediate query execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#immediate-query-execution), by calling ToList() for instance, you can bring all the data back to the client and then run your projection. Notice the addition of `ToList` before `Select`:

```
var data =Context.RoomAllocs.Where(c => c.Status == status)
.Include(p => p.Room).Include(p => p.Case).Include(p => p.Collector)
.ToList() // <---- DO THIS
.Select(
v => new CaseData
{
    CaseId = v.CaseID,
    Notes = v.Case.Notes,
    SubcategoryId = v.Case.SubcategoryId,
    RoomName = v.Room.Name,
    BreakType = v.Case.BreakType,
    color = GetBreakTypeColor(v),
    SubcategoryName = v.Case.Subcategory.Name,
    SUName = v.Collector.ForeName + "" + v.Collector.SurName,
    FDate = v.FDate,
    TDate = v.TDate

}
).ToList();
```

Comment: It is better to use `.AsEnumerable()` method

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov that won't execute the query